# Select mutiplos Mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Preciso buscar dados de uma tabela e completar com dados de outra tabela...

Tabela principal: agendatelefone
Tabela secundaria: bairro

```
principal: 
    [{"id":1,"tipo":"delivery","nome":"aaa","telefone":983585042,"endereco":"26 de outubro","logodouro":"av","numero":1965,"complemento":101,"bairro":"bela vista","senha":"dsadas","obs":"","pdtotal":0},{"id":2,"tipo":"delivery","nome":"aaa","telefone":999994242,"endereco":"26 de outubro","logodouro":"av","numero":1965,"complemento":101,"bairro":"horto","senha":"dsadas","obs":"","pdtotal":0}]


secundaria: 
    [{"id":1,"nome":"bela vista","valor":3},{"id":2,"nome":"horto","valor":6},{"id":3,"nome":"Centro","valor":1}]
```

gostaria de enviar o campo valor para a tabela principal que corresponde a cada bairro...

Comment: Porque o `id` da tabela bairro se repete? Ela não é `chave primária` (PK)? Se for PK, então você precisa gravar este `id` na tabela `agendatelefone` como uma `chave estrangeira` (FK). Se não for PK, você estará fazendo um relacionamento pelo nome do bairro e não pelo código, o que não é recomendado.

Comment: cara malz e pq esse não a a resposta correta foi um poco forjada os ids são primário sim.. seria 1 2 3... to fazendo pelo nome a relação, vou editar...

Comment: da uma olhada la... campo senha ele vai travar ele no pedido e no bairro ao cliente... mais por enquanto não ta fechado o código.. então estou relacionando pelo nome

Answer (score 0):

Solução

```
SELECT * FROM agendatelefone bro INNER JOIN bairro usr ON (bro.bairro = usr.nome)
```